# Show solution is an attracting center manifold.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

Consider the small solutions of the following system

\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=\epsilon x-x^3+xy \\
\dot{y}&=-y+y^2-x^2 \\
\dot{\epsilon}&=0
\end{align}

with $0<\epsilon\ll 1$. Show there exist a $\delta>0$ so that

$y=h(x,\epsilon), \quad \text{for} \quad |(x,\epsilon)|\leq\delta$

with $h$ smooth, is an attracting center manifold.

**Initial calculations:** We let $y=h(x,\epsilon)$ and substitute into the second equation

$$
h'(x)(\epsilon x - x^3 + xh) = -h+h^2-x^2
$$

Now let

\begin{align}
h(x,\epsilon)&=ax^2+bx\epsilon+c\epsilon+O((x,\epsilon)^3) \\
D_xh &= 2ax+b\epsilon+O((x,\epsilon)^2)
\end{align}

so that

\begin{align}
O(x,\epsilon)^3 = x^2(a+1)+b\epsilon+c\epsilon^2+O(x,\epsilon)^3
\end{align}

This yields that $a=-1$ and $b=c=0$ or

\begin{align}
h(x,\epsilon)=-x^2+O((x,\epsilon)^3)
\end{align}

I am not sure how this translates into the claim that $h(x,\epsilon)$ is an attracting center manifold for $|(x,\epsilon)|\leq \delta$ (or if this is the correct procedure). Can someone give an explanation ? Thanks.

Comment: I checked, there are some mistakes in your expansion; also, your formula for $D_x h$ was not correct. I edited this, but maybe you could go through the expansion once more and update your question? You can check my edits and go from there.